# How to build Robot Framework project with variables, keywords and test files separated in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

I want to build a Robot Framework project in Jenkins. My project structure is as follows:

Project

- ```
     Resources
                 variables.robot
                 keywords.robot
     Suites
                 TestSuite.robot
  ```

The files variables.robot and keywords.robot in Resources folder contain respectively project variables and keywords, while TestSuite.robot in Suites folder contains the tests.

With the follow command in Execute Windows batch command:

`robot Suites\TestSuite.robot`

the build fails because variables and keywords are not found.
Instead with the follow command:

`robot -d Resources\*robot -T Suites\TestSuite.robot`

the build fails because the files in Resources folder don't contain tests.

How can I include variables.robot and keywords.robot files?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: but in your TestSuite.robot you have a reference to the resource files? Can you show your minimal example of the code in the files?

Comment: Please show how you reference the resources in a test. It sounds like you're just not referencing them properly.

Answer (score 0):

[Robot will search PYTHONPATH](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#taking-resource-files-into-use) for files if they can't be found relative to the test file.

You can add the `Resources` folder to PYTHONPATH with the `--pythonpath` option (or `-P`) like this:

```
robot --pythonpath Resources Suites\TestSuite.robot
```